# Hadoop streaming command fails to work in R

Tags: mapreduce, rstudio, hadoop-streaming, rhadoop

I have installed hadoop 2.7.2 on ubuntu 16.04, and I have also installed Rstudio and Rhadoop (rmr2,rhdfs,rhbase) on a single node cluster. RHadoop packages are installed in this directory: "/home/hduser/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/". however, I get error when I use simple example and hadoop streaming fails . 
Blow is more detail:
Can anyone please help me out ?

[here is the Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rmkv.png)

I also get this warning message whenever I load rmr2 package:

> library("rmr2", lib.loc="~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2")
>   Warning message:
>   S3 methods ‘gorder.default’, ‘gorder.factor’, ‘gorder.data.frame’, ‘gorder.matrix’, ‘gorder.raw’ were declared in NAMESPACE but not found